# Difference in docker restart policy between on-failure and unless-stopped?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, restart

I have read the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/) about restart policy of containers.
However, I failed to understand the difference between `on-failure` and `unless-stopped`.

When will I use one over the other? In which situations will a certain policy lead to starting a container and the other policy not?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`on-failure` will issue a restart if the exit code indicated a failure, whereas `unless-stopped` behaves like `always` and will keep an instance running unless the container is stopped.

You can try with the hello-world to see the difference.

`docker run --restart on-failure hello-world` will run once and exit successfully, and running a subsequent `docker ps` will indicate no currently running instances of the container.

However, `docker run --restart unless-stopped hello-world` will restart the container even if it successfully exits, so subsequently running `docker ps` will show you a restarting instance until you stop the container.

```text
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                                  PORTS               NAMES
4d498ebd13a6        hello-world         "/hello"            2 seconds ago       Restarting (0) Less than a second ago                       modest_keldysh
```

Comment: I tried the example with `docker run --restart on-failure hello-world`, and it doesn't work like that. The container exits with 0 status and stops, it's not listed in `docker ps`. Only running with `--restart always` keep the hello-world container running. Why is that?

Comment: @AlexeyGrinko that's exactly what's stated in this answer

Comment: @Alexey Grinko Exit code 0 is good and therefore means no error, that is why the container will not restart with restart: on-failure. It will restart on exit code 1 for example.

Comment: Just an important note:
`unless-stopped` won't even restart them upon dockerd daemon restart!

Sauce: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy

Answer (score 40):

Docker restart policies are there to keep containers active in all possible downfalls, we can leverage it in multiple ways as an example if we have a web server running on a container and have to keep it active even on bad request we can use `unless-stopped` flag, it will keep the server up and running till we stopped it manually.

Restart flag can be any one of these :-

1. `"no"` :- it is the default value, and it will never restart the container.
2. `on-failure` :- it will restart the container whenever it encounters an error, or say, whenever the process running inside the container exit with non-zero exit code. Exit code :- 0 means no error, we terminated the process intentionally, but any non-zero value is an error.
3. `always` :- as the name, it will always restart the container, no matter whatever be the exit code is. Also, it will restart the container even when we manually stopped it but for that we need to restart the docker daemon.
4. `unless-stopped` :- it is similar to the `always` flag the only difference is once the container is stopped manually it will not restart automatically even after restarting the docker daemon, until we start the container manually again.

The difference between `unless-stopped` and `on-failure` is the first will always restart until we stopped it manually no matter whatever be the exit code will be and another will only restart the container on real failure, i.e. exit code = non-zero.

Once the container is stopped its restart flags are ignored, this is one way to overcome from restarting loop. That's why in the case of `always` flag once we stopped it manually the container will not restart till we restart the docker daemon.

You can easily test all of these flags by creating a simple *redis-server*:

```
 docker run -d --restart=always --name redis-server redis  # start redis image
 docker container ls # test the status 
 docker stop redis-server # stop the container manually
 docker container ls # test the status again, got the redis-server did not restarted 
 sudo service docker restart # restart the docker daemon 
 # test the status again will find the container is again up and running
 # try the same steps by changing the restart flag with *unless-stopped*
 docker update --restart=unless-stopped redis-server # will update the restart flag of running container.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "real failure"? Can the container stop automatically without leaving a non-zero exit code?